# How to put buttons with different sizes side by side programmatically?

Tags: android, kotlin

With a JSON that returns a dynamic list of buttons with different sizes, I need to show them side by side. Each row of the layout has four positions and each button can occupy 1, 2, 3 or 4 positions. How could I make this possible programmatically? Any suggestions would be very welcome.

Comment: Hi and welcome! What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi, I found a library that might work: https://github.com/jacobmoncur/QuiltViewLibrary